# How to update the shipping Address of an order?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have created an placeorder function that is placing order programmatically. Now, I need to another function which can update the shipping address of an order. 
I am using the below code, but it is giving error Call to a member function getId() on boolean in.

Please help me if anyone idea about this.

```
                $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($data['orderId']);

                $orderShippingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress()->getId();
                $orderShipping = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->load($orderShippingAddress);
                $shippingAddress
                    ->setPrefix($data['prefix'])
                    ->setFirstname($name[0])
                    ->setLastname($name[1])
                    ->setEmail($data['email'])
                    ->setCompany($data['houseNo'])
                    ->setStreet(array(
                         '0' => $data['area'], // compulsory
                         '1' => $data['landmark'] // optional
                     ))
                    ->setCity($data['city'])
                    ->setCountry_id('IN')
                    ->setRegion($data['state'])
                    ->setRegion_id($region_id)
                    ->setPostcode($data['pincode'])
                    ->setTelephone($data['telephone'])
                    ->setFax($data['bulidingName'])
                    ->setSaveInAddressBook(1)
                    ->save();
```

Comment: I am getting the post data in $data variable,

Comment: I have resolved the issue. The issue was I was trying to load the order using load function. But  I was passing increment_id instead of entity_id. So, solution was loadByIncrementId.